# os.rename(src,dir) cannot find specified file?

Tags: python, file, io, rename

I'm writing a program using python for a scout hut, to store information on scouts and be able to add/remove scouts. The spec said it HAS to use file handling to store scouts.

Upon writing the code for the remove scouts section, i encountered an issue with os.rename() command. I honestly don't understand why. The sed dir doesnt actually exist, is this my issue? The src dir does and i want to rename this to a different name. For example, i want to rename "IDTemp.txt" to "IDs.txt", without "IDs.txt" actually existing as a file. Is this possible?
Code below:

```
elif self._name == "rem":
            remID = str(scoutID.get())
            if remID != "":
                #store all the lines that are in the file in a temp file
                with open(fileName,"r") as f:
                    lines = f.readlines()
                    with open(tempFileName,"a") as ft:
                        for line in lines:
                            #splits the line by ',', then takes the last part. It then trims this to remove the '/n' prefix
                            sctID = str(line.split(",")[3])[:-1]
                            if sctID != remID: #if the ID we are looking to remove isn't
                                #the ID of the scout we are currently looking at, move it to the temp file
                                ft.write(line)
                            else:
                                #Remove the scout ID of the scout that is being removed from the ID file
                                with open(IDFileName,"r+") as fi:
                                    lines = fi.readlines()
                                    with open(IDTemp,"a") as ft:
                                        for line in lines:
                                            if line[:-1] != sctID:
                                                ft.write(line)
                        os.rename(IDTemp,IDFileName)

                #remove the main file, then rectrate a new one
                os.remove(fileName)
                file = open(fileName,"a")
                file.close()

                #copy all the lines back to the main file
                with open(tempFileName,"r") as tf:
                    lines = tf.readlines()
                    with open(fileName,"a") as f:
                        for line in lines:
                            f.write(line)
                #finally, delete and recreate the temp file
                os.remove(tempFileName)
                file = open(tempFileName,"a")
                file.close()
            #remove the window    
            master.destroy()
```

Output:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\KRIS\Documents\Python Projects\Scouts\popupWindow.py", line     88, in _callback
    os.rename(IDTemp,IDFileName)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:     'C:\\Users\\KRIS\\Scouts\\Temp\\IDTemp.txt' ->     'C:\\Users\\KRIS\\Scouts\\Temp\\IDs.txt'
```

Comment: Where is `IDTemp` created?  What happens if `sctID != remID`?

Comment: @cdarke the code is well commented. As stated, the line is written to the temp file if the ID isnt the one we want to remove. IDTemp is created in my main class when the program is run

Comment: You need the source file to exist, and it doesn't...
Use os.path.exists and print (or raise...) if you have a doubt.

Comment: @EricLevieil The source file does exist at that point, as it is created when `with open(IDTemp,"a") as ft` is called

Comment: using an actual tempfile would be a nicer implementation, you also don't need to always call readlines just iterate over the file object

Comment: *IDTemp is created in my main class when the program is run*  that code is not shown, and I don't see a comment to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by rewriting the section of code, and copied the IDs from temp to a new copy of the main ID file, leaving behind the ID to remove `remID`. I then deleted the temp file.